# Django iteration (for ... in ...) how to put it in different divs?

Tags: django

I have few instances of model.

my model:

```
class Record(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(Car)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
    created = models.DateTimeField(
            default=timezone.now)
```

view:

```
def allrecords(request):
    records = Record.objects.all().order_by('created')
    return render(request, 'mycar/allrecords.html', {'records' : records})
```

I want show it on my website. In my template i have:

```
{% for record in records %}
    <img src={{ record.image.url}}/>
    <div>
        {{record.name}}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Now i get list of my records, but i would like put the newest record to first div, next to second etc. How can i do that?

I show simple screen how i would like have that (if someone will create new record, it will go to first div and other records will change place. Is any possibility to do something like that?
[image: screen]

edit:

```
<div>
    {% for record in records %}
        {% if forloop.counter == 1 %}
            <img src={{ record.image.url}}/>
            <div>
                {{record.name}}
            </div>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</div>

<div>
    {% for record in records %}
        {% if forloop.counter == 2 %}
            <img src={{ record.image.url}}/>
            <div>
                {{record.name}}
            </div>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</div>


        .
        .
        # till your 5th image
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `forloop.counter` to get the iteration number and check what is the iteration the loop and handle data accordingly.

In addition you can use CSS to make the layout work as you want.

[Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#for) is the information for  Django template counter

**Edit :**

```
{% for record in records %}
    <div>
    {% if forloop.counter == 1 %}

    # Here you can get your first images

        <img src={{ record.image.url}}/>
        <div>
            {{record.name}}
        </div>

    {% endif %}
    </div>
    <div>
    {% if forloop.counter == 2 %}

    # Here you can get your first images

        <img src={{ record.image.url}}/>
        <div>
            {{record.name}}
        </div>

    {% endif %}
    </div>
    .
    .
    # till your 5th image


{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. When i used your solution it iterated through divs so it created with each forloop.counter 5 new divs. Next I tried put 'for - endfor' only into div in which i wanted this record and it is ok, but you think is it good way to start 'for - endfor' each time i iterate? I pasted my working solution into my first post, if you could check it, because it is working and i am wondering is it ok with django and python standards?

Comment: I have edited the original answer and I think having too any many for loops is unnecessary, you can achieve the same using single one

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this. If you want to set this option for a single view then:

```
def all_records(request):
    records = Record.objects.all().order_by('-created')
    return render(request, 'mycar/allrecords.html', {'records' : records})
```

You're almost correct but order_by('created') leads to asceding order while order_by('-created') leads to descending order which is what you require.

Alternatively, if you want to have this setting to apply to all views then set class Meta in your models.py which will ensure that wherever you use Record.objects.all() it returns Records in descending order of created field:

```
class Record(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(Car)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
    created = models.DateTimeField(
            default=timezone.now)

    class Meta:
       ordering = ('-created')
```

It's Django design pattern to make all logical decisions in models and views and only just plugin formatted data in templates. You shouldn't add any complex logic in templates.

Comment: I agree with this answer if the question is about ordering -- I assumed it was about iterating and treating the first image and every third image (new row) differently.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the question means that the model might have more than 5 records.  If so, a more generic solution would be

```
<div class='row'>
    <div class='firstimage'>
        <img src={{ records[0].image.url}}/>
        {{record.name}}
    </div>
    {% for record in records %}
        {% if forloop.counter > 1 %}
            <div class='subsequentimage'>
                <img src={{ record.image.url}}/>
                {{record.name}} 
            </div>
        {% endif %} 
        {% cycle "" "</div><div class='row'>" "" %}
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Note the use of the 'cycle' tag to begin a new row div every third cell div.

I don't know what your CSS classes are to distinguish between rows and cells so I used 'row', 'firstimage' (which might be defined to take up twice as much width) and 'subsequentimage' as example classes.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use the context variables:

```
def all_records(request):
   records = Record.objects.all().order_by('-created')
   newest = records[:5]
   oldest = records[5:]
   return render(request, 'mycar/allrecords.html', {'newst' : newest,
                                                   'oldest': oldest })
```

In your template :

```
{% for new in newst %}
 <div>what you want with news</div>
{% endfor %}

{% for old in oldest %}
 <div>what you want with olds</div>
{% endfor %}
```